# recommended brushes to replicate this sculpture

Tags: sculpting

As a beginner I am wondering could some-one give me some tips regarding the most suitable brushes to replicate this picture.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I mean you can literally do this with any brushes, just dig deep enough into mesh with Layer set to subtract (if you are a beginner, you can easily press ctrl to make it subtract from your mesh instead of add), then you can tweak it with any other brushes and just learn them and try to use them... I don't think there is a specific manual to do this exactly.

Comment: @MikoCG...great thanks for the tip.